# Java - universal getter

Tags: java, object, getter, instanceof

I have a collection of Objects:

```
public LinkedHashMap<String, Object> objectList;
```

and I want to get a String value, or Integer value by this method:

```
public Object getValue(String key) {
  if (objectList.get(key) instanceof String) { 
    return ((String) objectList.get(key));
  }
}
```

After, I want use this getter:

```
String value = getValue("someKey");
```

But this is not working, and I don´t know why. The getter returns Object, but if this is it instance of String, I cast it to String.

Can you tell me why it does not work? Or some other solution.

Thanks.

Comment: The return type of the method is `Object`, so no matter what you do inside the method, the returning reference type will be `Object`. You will have to cast it to `String` after it returns in this case.

Comment: And where do you think you cast it to String? You don't. You can also write `public <T> T getValue(String key)`, then you won't need to cast. Method implementation should say `return (T) objectList.get(key);`

Comment: This code doesn't compile, BTW, since you don't return anything if the value is not a String. You should also choose better names: objectList should refer to a List, not a Map.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public<T extends Object> T getValue(String key) {
    return (T) objectList.get(key);
}
```

But be very careful with such things!

Comment: `<T extends Object>` is redundant. You could simply write `public <T>  T getValue(String key) { ... }`.